# What's the value of $\theta$ in Lagrange's form of remainder $R_{n}$ for the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The n-th remainder in the expression of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ , $R_{n}$ = $\frac{x^n}{n!}f^n(\theta x)$ . 
And, $f^n(\theta x)$ = $\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(1-\theta x)^{n+1}}$
I have to evaluate the value of $\theta$ here. But I'm clueless about what steps to take. I've tried expanding $\frac{1}{1-x}$ into its polynomial form but i cannot derive anything from it. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that the $n$th derivative is actually $n!(1-x)^{-n-1}$: the $-1$s from the power and chain rule cancel.

You actually have an analytic expression for the remainder:
$$ \frac{1}{(1-\theta x)^{n+1}}x^n = R_n = \frac{1}{1-x}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k. $$
The right-hand side is of course
$$ \frac{1}{1-x}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} = \frac{x^n}{1-x}. $$
And hence by cancelling and reciprocating both sides,
$$ (1-\theta x)^{n+1} = 1-x, $$
so
$$\theta = \frac{1-(1-x)^{1/(n+1)}}{x}. $$

Comment: Thanks. Understood.